# Activity always be on top and act as a parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to make an application which prevents other applications to launch without user password form my app , I have locked other apps from my application but with some applications when their splash screen ends it automatically launch their respective activity on my password activity and my password activity remains behind that activity.Hope you got what I want to say.Thanx for any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make an application which prevents other applications to launch without user password form my app

That's simply not possible...thankfully.

Comment: Very well said Sir but a way to make my activity on top of that application activity which user wants to protect,I have Done that but facing bit problem with some splash screens methods of applications which uses thread to start other activity.When that application runs my password activity comes on top of that activity and when form that splash screen activity thread runs it starts their respective activty on front off my password activity...